# Fast and simple blog software

Tags: cms

It should run on an Apache server with MySQL. It should be fast, simple to learn, easy to update and secure.

Nice features would be a simple customizable design, login feature, manage pages/articles, timestamp/author name on articles, categories, SEO, WYSIWYG-editor.

Is there a better solution than Wordpress?

Comment: What are the features you want that aren't in WordPress?

Comment: Wordpress is too overloaded with junk and slower than a slim blogging cms.